# Ajax Auto Refresh to update couple div's depend on one value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good Afternoon,

I am using Eliza Witkowska's Ajax Auto Refresh code: [http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii](http://Eliza%20Witkowska's%20Ajax%20Auto%20Refresh%20code:%20http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii)

Now what is I'm trying to achieve is to select data from database and split them to 3 div's depends on value of field `dish_type` which is integers.

So far after consultancy with Eliza I have gone there:

My **db.php** file:

```
    function get_news(){    
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT t1.* FROM fandb t1 JOIN (SELECT tableno, MAX(add_date) add_date FROM fandb GROUP BY tableno ASC) t2 ON t1.tableno = t2.tableno AND t1.add_date = t2.add_date WHERE id<>1;')){

$return = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
if (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='1') { $dish='STARTER'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='2') { $dish='MAIN COURSE'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='3') { $dish='DESSERT'; }
            if (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='1') { $class_n='id="kitchen_tab_starter"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='2') { $class_n='id="kitchen_tab_main"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='3') { $class_n='id="kitchen_tab_dessert"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->dish_type).''=='0') { $class_n='id="kitchen_tab_done"'; }

switch((int)$r->title){
    case 1:
        $arr= array(

            /* the id of a div that you want to update */
            'destination'=>'#kitchen_tab_starter',

            /* the html that will replace current html
            in div#kitchen_tab_starter */
            'html'=>'<button '.$class_n.'><div class="fontbig">'.htmlspecialchars($r->tableno).'</div><div class="fontsmall">'.$dish.'</font></div></button>'

        );
        $return[] = $arr;
    break;
    case 2:
        $arr= array(
            'destination'=>'#kitchen_tab_main',
            'html'=>'<button '.$class_n.'><div class="fontbig">'.htmlspecialchars($r->tableno).'</div><div class="fontsmall">'.$dish.'</font></div></button>'
        );
        $return[] = $arr;
    break;
    case 3:
        $arr= array(
            'destination'=>'#kitchen_tab_dessert',
            'html'=>'<button '.$class_n.'><div class="fontbig">'.htmlspecialchars($r->tableno).'</div><div class="fontsmall">'.$dish.'</font></div></button>'
        );
        $return[] = $arr;
    break;
    /* ... and so on */
}
}
return $return;
        }
    }
```

My **index.php** file

Checker code part:

```
    <script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
            $('#div1').html(response.news);
                 $('#div2').html(response.news);
                 $('#div3').html(response.news);
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,2000);
</script>
```

Display part

```
    <div id="kitchen_tab_starter" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
        <div id="kitchen_tab_main" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
        <div id="kitchen_tab_dessert" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
```

And unfortunetly it doesnt work as I wish, I mean it doesnt work at all.
Have you got any ideas any suggestions to navigate me to how I can get this to work as I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid in your .done method you are not using the right ids

```
...
}).done(function( response ) {
        /* update counter */
        $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
        /* check if with response we got a new update */
        if(response.update==true){
        $('#div1').html(response.news);
             $('#div2').html(response.news);
             $('#div3').html(response.news);
        }
    });
```

If that not the case, can you verify if your ajax call go back to the done method and have the requested data?

Comment: Oh god, so I have just change this to:

`.done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#div1').data('counter',response.current);
            $('#div2').data('counter',response.current);
            $('#div3').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
            $('#div1').html(response.news);
                 $('#div2').html(response.news);
                 $('#div3').html(response.news);
            }
        });`

And data does not show auto, only after normal refresh

Comment: try to see what is exactly in the variable "response.news" and check is right format HTML code and be sure the container where is doing the .html() is a div, not input, span,...

Comment: so I have viewed resonse.news and it does return `undefined`

Comment: Thats your main problem, try to use firebug, or some developer console to see exactly what is your response returning. In the moment you return the right html code should be injected correctly to the div.

Comment: In Lint Javascritp debugger it does shows me `if(response.update==true){
     ====================================^
     lint warning: comparisons against null, 0, true, false, or an empty string allowing implicit type conversion (use === or !==)
 24              $('#div1').html(response.news);
 25                   $('#div2').html(response.news);
 26                   $('#div3').html(response.news);
 27              }`

Answer (score 0):

I have bypassed the issue by duplicating functions in files so now I do have 3  functions: **get_news1 get_news2 get_news3** in **db.php** file, I had to make relevant changes in **index.php** with ajax checker and div's on the bottom
So copying:

```
    <script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list1').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list1').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list1').html(response.news);
                var audio = new Audio('ding.mp3');
            audio.play();
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,2000);
</script>
```

And replacing `#message-list1` to `message-list2` etc. and in the bottom of the file adding divs as below:

```
    <div class="show_tables" id="message-list1" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news1();?>
</div>
```

And again duplicating them with changes as above.

Last change you have to make is in **checker.php** file where functions are called from **db.php** file to call out your `get_news#` functions

in my example as per below:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && (int)$_POST['counter']!=$data['current']){
//the counters are diffrent so get new message list
$data['news'] .= $db->get_news1();
$data['news2'] .= $db->get_news2();
$data['news3'] .= $db->get_news3();
$data['news4'] .= $db->get_last_orders();
$data['update'] = true;
```

}

where `$data['news1']` etc is called in ajax function in index file and `$db->get_news1();` etc are your functions from db.php file.

Hope this will help someone in future.
Im sure there is easier way of doing this however this is working for me.

Good Luck!